# More "random" alternative to shuf for selecting files in a directory

Tags: bash, random

I put together the following Bash function (in my `.bashrc`) to open a "random" image from a given folder, one at a time until the user types <kbd>N</kbd>, after which it exits. The script works fine aside from the actual randomness of the images generated - in a quick test of 10 runs, only 4 images are unique.

Is this simply unavoidable due to the limited number of images in the directory (20), or is there an alternative to the `shuf` command that will yield more random results?

If it is unavoidable, what's the best way to adapt the function to avoid repeats (i.e. discard images that have already been selected)?

```
function generate_image() {
    while true; do
        command cd "D:\Users\Hashim\Pictures\Data" && 
        image="$(find . -type f -exec file --mime-type {} \+ | awk -F: '{if ($2 ~/image\//) print $1}' | shuf -n1)" &&
        echo "Opening $image" &&
        cygstart "$image"
        read -p "Open another random image? [Y/n]"$'\n' -n 1 -r
        echo
        if [[ $REPLY =~ ^[Nn]$ ]] 
        then exit
        fi 
    done
}
```

Comment: If by "more random" you mean "more likely to be perceived as random by a human", that's a research topic, and more one for a psych department than computer science

Comment: (...I'm reminded of some of Britain's WW2 codes being broken on account of the keying material being chosen by old ladies pulling balls out of mixing baskets thought the numbers didn't look random enough, and substituting more-random-looking, but actually _less_-random, values instead).

Comment: If you want to avoid repeats, shuffle the entire list of files and iterate over the results. Don't call `shuf` again until you've exhausted the whole list. In other words, don't limit the output to one file at a time (`shuf -n1`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I do, hence the scare quotes, I'm aware it's only pseudorandom, but `shuf` has been around for a while; surely that research has already been done by now.

Comment: My point is that even remotely-competent pseudorandomness is much better than what a human can detect (without entropy measurement). What you really care about here is avoiding repeats, and that calls for more statefulness.

Comment: Which specific version of bash are you targeting? (`echo "$BASH_VERSION"`). Also, do you know if process substitutions work in i t? (I've seen them be broken in some Windows builds even when the feature worked fine in the same version of bash on Linux).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy 4.4.12, and they do to the best of my knowledge, in general Cygwin is a very faithful emulation of a UNIX-like system, much more so than WSL2 and others.

Comment: Cygwin _tries_ to be faithful, but it still has bugs. I saw that last one only a few years ago; I suppose we'll find out if it's still there when you try my answer. :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy True, Cygwin's main problem is that it's old and its development is slow,  but it's still superior to any of the competitors.

Comment: Eh, I don't think I agree with that. WSL2 being syscall-layer emulation rather than library-layer emulation lets it be a lot closer in some very meaningful ways.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I got put off WSL2 when I realised how slow it still is compared to Cygwin, and then not having block-level access to devices with `/dev/sdX` like Cygwin gives was the ultimate dealbreaker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to handle this is by searching the filesystem and creating an array with a list of files in randomized order, and going through everything in that list before searching again.

Because you go through everything from one batch of `shuf` output before starting the next batch of `shuf` output, there's no longer a risk of repeats until everything has been seen.

```
refresh_image_list() {
  # respect prior image_dir value if set before the function is called
  image_dir=${image_dir:-'D:/Users/Hashim/Pictures/Data'}
  readarray -d '' image_list < <(
    find "$image_dir" -type f -exec file -0 --mime-type -- {} + \
    | while IFS= read -r -d '' filename && IFS= read -r desc; do
        [[ $desc = *image* ]] && printf '%s\0' "$filename"
      done \
    | shuf -z
  )
}

generate_image() {
  while true; do
    (( ${#image_list[@]} )) || refresh_image_list  # if list is empty, recreate
    set -- "${image_list[@]}"              # set argument list from image list
    while (( $# )); do                     # argument list isn't empty?
      echo "Opening $1"                    # ...try the first item on it
      cygstart "$1"
      shift                                # ...and then discard that item
      read -p $'Open another random image? [Y/n]\n' -n 1 -r
      echo
      if [[ $REPLY = [Nn] ]]; then         # user wants to quit?
        image_list=( "$@" )                # store unused images back to list
        return 0
      fi
    done
  done
}
```

---

We can simplify this if we're willing to just stop after the user has seen every image once, instead of generating a new batch, and don't need persistence across invocations:

```
generate_image() {
  while IFS= read -r -d '' filename <&3; do
    echo "Opening $filename"
    cygstart "$filename"
    read -p $'Open another random image? [Y/n]\n' -n 1 -r
    echo
    [[ $REPLY = [Nn] ]] && return 0
  done 3< <(
    find "$image_dir" -type f -exec file -0 --mime-type -- {} + \
    | while IFS= read -r -d '' filename && IFS= read -r desc; do
        [[ $desc = *image* ]] && printf '%s\0' "$filename"
      done \
    | shuf -z
  )
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's a lot more complicated an approach than I expected when you described it. I'll try it and get back to you.

Comment: It _could_ be simpler. For example, you could use a `while read` loop to directly consume the output of `find`. The advantage of doing it this way is that you can exit one generate_image function call, start a new one, and (as long as you're running this as a function in your interactive shell, vs a subprocess running in its own shell) it'll pick up where you left off in the ordering. Personally, I think that's worth a little extra code.

Comment: While it looks very code-golfy to me (i.e. using tricks for conciseness rather than idiomatic, easily understandable Bash) and I prefer idiomatic Bash for learning purposes, I just tested this and it does work perfectly, and I especially appreciate the comments. For all I know it just looks that way to me and this is the standard way to do something like this in Bash, I do remember arrays being a nightmare.

Comment: I do have two questions: 1) as I'm on Windows and won't ever have a filename with colons or newlines, how would that first part be simplified for better performance? 2) Would moving the variable and the first function inside of the second one affect the logic at all? I want to avoid the confusion of cluttering my Bash functions with nested functions as much as possible.

Comment: I'm never one to play code golf: When there are fancy "tricks" in my code, they're for _correctness_, not conciseness; and I'm very hesitant to compromise correctness here on Stack Overflow, where people who _aren't_ on Windows can potentially read and try to use answers.

Comment: Regarding your first aside about `cygpath`, I haven't needed to use it for years and can't even recall seeing it outside of scripts. I can't honestly remember how it used to be, but modern Cygwin handles both Cygwin and Windows paths effortlessly.

Comment: Quick question: How important is using `file` instead of relying on extensions to you? At least from a performance perspective, that's the most expensive design decision here.

Comment: ...that said, with modern GNU `file`, there's a `-0` option, so yes, it should be possible to simplify that code safely; let me play with it for a minute.

Comment: @HashimAziz, there we are -- see the new definition of `refresh_image_list`. It's not really shorter -- I'm disappointed by that -- but it's definitely faster, especially when the number of images is large.

Comment: @HashimAziz, ...I also added a simplified version that just stops after each image has been seen once.

Comment: The performance gains from not using `file` wouldn't really justify the robustness it adds to the script for me, including the convenience of not needing to keep track of (and add to the script) the extensions of the images in the directory. Regardless, I sincerely appreciate your help with this and all the time you've spent on it, thank you.

Comment: To answer my own second question, I was able to move the variable and the outer function inside of the generator function to keep my `.bashrc` as modular and organised as possible - based on my testing this doesn't seem to have any affect on the functionality or randomness of the code, so I'll go ahead and edit that into your code to make it more clearly understood as a Bash function, but feel to revert the edit if you'd rather keep it the way it was.

Comment: @HashimAziz, the goal of setting the variable outside the function was to let people who aren't you test the code by copy-and-pasting the function without changes and setting their own value for the variable separately. I've edited it to be set inside _as a default_ but honor any prior value.

Answer (score 2):

Charles' answer is definitely the superior answer here, but for completeness I thought I would also add a middle-ground solution that I stumbled across while experimenting earlier on.

I learnt that `shuf` can be seeded with an external source of randomness, so by seeding it with `/dev/urandom` - the randomness generator device available on all UNIX-like systems - it can be made more random:

```
shuf -n1 --random-source=/dev/urandom
```

From my tests this appears to result in significantly fewer repeats than a standard `shuf` command, and could be an ideal solution if you want a little more randomness but can tolerate the occasional repeat.

Comment: Interesting. If this is in fact a perceptible difference, I wonder how `shuf` is otherwise seeding its PRNG. If it's doing it by time, f/e, that could explain repeats if going through the list with less than a second between iterations.

Answer (score 1):

file listings are rarely so gigantic it can't fit into RAM for `awk` :

```
 find … -print0 |

 mawk 'BEGIN {    FS = "\0"
              _^= RS = "^$" 
       } END { printf("%*s", srand()*!_, $(int(rand()*(NF-_))+_)) }'
```

That'll randomly print out the filename for one of the image files found, with no trailing byte of either `\0` or `\n`, without having to perform any sort of sorting/shuffling.

`NF - 1` because `find` prints out final `\0`, so NF count is always 1 more than # of files found.

It also protects against an empty input instead of referencing a negative field number - simply nothing gets printed at all.

From there, you can decide you want to open this image file.

Comment: The OP already has `shuf` working perfectly well for them; why show how to replace something that isn't the part with the problem? (The issue isn't caused by using `shuf`; the problem is caused by using `shuf -n1` -- it would be like taking the awk code you gave here and then only reading the first piece of output from it)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : this is also the part where you only read half of my code then comment - with the approach i suggested, (1) no one has to waste time sorting or shuffling, (2) shuf's repeat flag is really bad :  `jot 5 | shuf -r | mawk 'NR==1000{exit} 1' | uniqC
             224 1
             199 2
             167 3
             204 4
             205 5` - that's a rather ridiculous distribution of 5 items repeated 200 times each. i'm surprised you believe `shuf` has a good algorithm at all, and (3) unlike sorting based approaches, mine does away with sorting algo peculiarities,

Comment: Again, the OP's goal isn't really that things be "more random", their goal is that they stop seeing repeats. Note that they accepted an answer that goes from random selection with replacement to random selection _without_ replacement: it's not more random at all, it just guarantees they won't see repeated items, but given the context and purpose (of displaying images to the user in an order that user would interpret as random), _that's what they actually want_. This answer doesn't pay any attention at all to the purpose of the OP's original script, or discuss correct use in context of same.

Comment: Criticizing someone for only reading half your code is thus a bit rich -- as far as I can tell, your read of the question stopped at its title, without paying any attention to the body.

Comment: (as for the `jot 5 | shuf -r` demonstration above, I'd need to do some statistics before it was at all "obvious" that the distribution is wrong).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : yeah how hard to is it to keep running more and more trials until the variance properly narrows enough to fit within your desired narrative ?

Comment: Avoiding that is exactly the point of doing statistics instead of just eyeballing it and making unfounded statements about what looks "ridiculous". (I'm not saying `shuf` is good; I'm saying until there's actual analysis there's no proof either way).

Comment: Massaging numbers to perfectly fit a probability curve often makes them _less_ random, not more; so "each value happens the same number of times" is not, strictly speaking, a thing to aspire to. (You want them to have the same _probability_, but that doesn't mean they have the same incidence count in any given run).